# LinqTOEntities difference beteen Exists and contains

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

what is the difference between using `exists` over `contains`

```
var s = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
dbset.where(x => s.contains(x.id);
```

or

```
var s = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
dbset.Where(x => s.Exists(y => x.id));
```

Comment: `Exists()` doesn't exist.

Comment: There is no such method as Exists.

Comment: To clarify, [Exists()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx) is exposed by `List<T>`. Your `s` is an array, not a list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfed8bca.aspx) is a method of `List<T>`, there is no such method on array or `IEnumerable<T>` extensions.
2. Correct syntax of usage of this method is `x => s.Exists(y => y == x.id)` (you should pass predicate, i.e. method which returns boolean)
3. The difference is - `Contains` supported by Linq to Entities, `Exists` is not supported.

Comment: +1, you did much better in explaining the difference between these two methods, than I. But could you also describe the difference between passing a raw value and a predicate? I just think this is crucial in understanding the key difference between these two methods (Because EF supports `Any` instead of `Exists`, so it's not like a big problem\difference here)

Comment: @IlyaIvanov sorry, didn't get you here :) Predicate is a part of Exists method signature, difference between passing raw value and predicate is simple - you either call this method with predicate, or your code do not compile

Comment: Well, for example, you can capture local variable in a predicate and access it in a predicate, thus creating more flexible conditions for comparison. ANYWAY - lets leave it for self study. Speaking about syntax - you answer is perfectly valid :)